# how to set an mvc object to a variable within webform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC application with a link to print the information. the print link is inside a javascript. 
code as follows:

```
<td>
<%= Html.TextBox("Name", Model.ApplicantStatus.Name) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*") %>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myEmail = "ChangeMe@abc.org";
var mySubject = "Sample";
var myBody = "My name is ";
var myName = Model.TableName.Name;
document.write('<a href="mailto:' + myEmail + '?subject=' + mySubject + '&body=' + myBody + myname + '">email me</a>');
</script>
```

---

basically var myName = Model.TableName.Name; is not working. any workarounds?

Comment: i'm in a hurry that i didnt notice i have to indent the code.
thanks mate for the replies -
 var myName = '<%=Model.TableName.Name%>';

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to

```
 var myName = <%=Model.TableName.Name%>;
```